# Uploading a file from a wpf application to a web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload a file (image) from a WPF application to a Web Api controller. In the controller I convert the file into a bit array and save it in a DB. I used the following code for sending files to web api

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UploadFile("URI", "POST", "filepath");
```

In my web api I am checking if the incoming request is MimemultipartContent

```
if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
```

This works fine. But when I try to send a data buffer instead of a file I am stuck how to write my server side code.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes('filepath');
client.UploadData("URI", "POST", bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. It's simple actually.

```
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var bytes = task.Result;
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        img.ImageData = bytes;
        db.Images.Add(img);
        db.SaveChanges();
```